# Choose license with extremely modified parts from another script

Tags: javascript, licensing

So I've got a JavaScript script that uses extremely modified pieces of another script. That script has an GNU General Public License. Do I need to use that license too or can I choose my own and just reference to that other script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your own licence, you have to rip out all the bits that actually came from the GPL'd script. This is because the GPL is a "strong copyleft" (or as some would call it, "viral") licence that requires anything that it's merged with to be licensed under GPL also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've adjusted over 95% and added a whole lot more. Is this sufficient or do I need to change every character?

Comment: Basically, is it likely that the original author is going to try to claim ownership of the rest? The crux of it is that you need to have _full_ copyright ownership of the code before you can use a non-GPL licence.